# When two words require different prepositions

Tags: prepositions

> He is senior **to** and older **than** I.
>   His dress is different **from** and cheaper **than** mine.
>   She is younger and taller than her sister.

In the first two sentences we have used two preposition after the required words. So, why had we not followed the same rule for the last sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparative adjectives require a *than* before the thing that we are comparing with. The words *younger* and *taller* are both comparative adjectives, and we need to use *than* after them.

*Senior* can have a meaning similar to *older*. However, it's not a comparative adjective. The comparative construction for *senior* is *more senior than*. The normal adjective *senior* takes a preposition phrase headed by *to*:

- He is senior **to me**.
- He is more senior **than me**.

*Different* is also not a comparative adjective in the grammatical sense - although we do use it to compare things. When we use it on its own, it takes a preposition phrase headed by *from*, or occasionally *to*. Notice that *different* doesn't mean *more different*. If we use a comparative like this, then like with the other comparatives, we need the preposition *than*:

- She's very different **to me**.
- She's very different **from me**.
- Those twins are more different **than these ones**.

If we use different adjectives in one sentence then we need to use the correct preposition for each adjective. If the adjectives take the same preposition then we can sometimes omit the first preposition:

- Bertha is senior **to** and cleverer **than** Bob
- Bertha is older [**than**] and cleverer **than** Bob.

Answer (score 2):

Both "younger" and "taller" would have been followed by "than" if used alone. So "She is younger **than** and taller **than** her sister", although not technically incorrect, would sound a little repetitive.